# Question about removing Gapps (Lollipop)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, privacy, huawei

I have some questions about removing Gapps.

I have Huawei P8 Lite with Android 5.0.1. I want to put CM or AOSP on it, but it seems that there are no custom ROMs available as of yet. I decided the least I can do then is root the phone and remove Gapps (due to privacy concerns).

Now, what would be the best way to do this? Is there a method of removing Gapps that applies to all Android phones or does it depend on Android version or even phone model itself? I am asking this because I've found some script to remove Gapps, but it's for Android 4.1 and I'm not sure if that would work for 5.0.1.

My other question is how does stock ROM behave when you remove Gapps since it's designed with Gapps in mind and they're part of the design? For example, if I remove Gapps, what happens to entries in settings that concern Google (such as keyboard, voice, search, etc.)? Will they disappear or remain? If I click them, will they cause a crash?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to uninstal Gapps once installed in an OS. Are you sure there are no alternatives? Have you looked for unofficial builds?

Comment: They can be uninstalled as long as the phone is rooted. Here's the script I mentioned in OP (I hope I'm allowed to post links): https://gist.github.com/olivier-m/6200184 Also there are applications like Root uninstaller and System app remover that can remove just about anything, but of course there's always risk of removing something important or even vital.